# jquery fire a click anywhere within a dialog box

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a Dialog Window, with a 2 by 2 table. instead of clicking on a button, i want to be able to click on any cell and it returns the value/text in an alert box. However i am unsure where i would place the following `alert($(event.target).text());` into ?

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

here is the code **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/4782/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a click event to `th,td`(According to your markup) if you need cell text.

```
$("#dialog-message th,td").click(function(event){
    alert($(event.target).text());  //$(this).text() would work too.
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/4783/)